# SELECT from MYSQL when only one single line present

Tags: php, mysql, database, select

I have this mysql query:

```
SELECT a.full_address 
FROM games_server AS a 
JOIN orders_order AS b 
ON b.server_id = a.id 
WHERE service_type = 'color' 
AND status = 'running' ORDER BY RAND()"
```

It works perfectly fine and selects a value only if service_type is 'color'.
But what I need is that it would select 'full_address' only when there's just one line with service_type = color and no other lines with different service_type values. Because for one full_address = a there might be multiple lines. E.g. full_address = a with service_type = color and the same full_address = a with service_type = top. In that particular instance, when there are two of them - it mustn't be selected. Only when there is one single line with service_type = color.

I hope any one understood what I said. Sorry if I couldn't make it any clearer.

Comment: It would be more helpful to understand you question if you post some sample data and expected output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this one (suppose games_server have id):

```
SELECT a.full_address FROM games_server AS a 
JOIN orders_order AS b ON b.server_id = a.id 
WHERE status = 'running' 
GROUP BY a.id
HAVING group_concat(distinct service_type) = 'color'
ORDER BY RAND()
```

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion! But unfortunately it returned blank.

Comment: yupp, sorry for that, forgot to add GROUP BY, hope you primary key for games_server is "id"

Comment: Worked like a charm. You're a life saver! Thank's a lot man. :)

Answer (score 0):

If I have understood your problem correctly, a sub query should be useful here.

```
SELECT a.full_address 
FROM games_server AS a 
JOIN orders_order AS b 
ON b.server_id = a.id 
WHERE service_type in 
        (select service_type 
         from orders_order 
         group by service_type 
         having COUNT(service_type)=1)
AND status = 'running' ORDER BY RAND()
```